# Recyclerview on Scrolling values changing from adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app where I am trying to populate a list using RecyclerView and recycler adapter as well. But when I scroll through the list quickly sometimes values on the list item shuffles among list items. Is there a known fix for this?

Comment: items cannot change by themselves,  most likely you are changing them in your adapter

Comment: what I meant to say is that the contents are shuffling among list items

Comment: use viewholder pattern carefully or if your list size is small set setIsRecyclable(false); try this.

Comment: where to put setIsRecyclable(false) ?@KundanKumarRoy

Comment: @KundanKumarRoy just post your answer and I will accept it, it did solve my problem

Comment: You do know setItsReyclable(true) defeats the purpose of the RecyclerView and should only be used in certain situations (this not being one of them).

Comment: i do realize that but it is an emergency situation, if  you know the correct way please post here and I will implement it tomorrow

Comment: inside your onBindViewHolder  add this  holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

Comment: did it, and it works

Comment: when i m doing this holder.setIsRecyclable(false); its stop populating rows data how to avoid data index mismatch ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

adding this in the adapter solved the problem

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```

Comment: This worked...But can someone please explain how this worked??

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < convobeans.size() && convobeans.get(position) != null) {
            final ConvoResponseModel.DataBean.ConversationBean conversationBean = convobeans.get(position);
           iint i = conversationBean.getIs_me();
            if (i == 1) {
                return RECEIVER_VIEW;
            } else {
                return SENDER_VIEW;
            }
        }
//        return super.getItemViewType(position);
        return position;
    } i have this code for a chat module but the size  keeps changing

Comment: can anyone guys explain how this works ? it worked for me but I want to know what is happening behind, thanks !

Comment: The answer maybe resolve your problem. But it causes broken recycling. Each row has a unique type.

Comment: @zakjma why do you think that it is broken?

Comment: each position(row number) has a unique type. So, RecyclerView can't recycle.

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation on what this does and why it's not recommended to do so with an alternate optimal solution below. Check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396998/5516474

Answer (score 18):

Just Override these methods in your adapter class:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

This link will help you to get the understanding of the concept behind.

[How to fix Recyclerview shuffling issue](https://www.solutionspirit.com/on-scrolling-recyclerview-change-values/)

Comment: Returning getItemViewType as position is basically asking to draw every view again and nothing gets recylcled. You might as well set viewholder.setIsRecylable(false) while creating viewholder. But this would defeat the purpose of having a recylerview. This answer just masks the real issue

Comment: also it just stopped my click event, i don't know why..

Answer (score 6):

Just have to override two methods in your Adapter and it will solve your issue.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Greate...It works for me

Answer (score 6):

**Note: I strongly recommend not to use any solution that suggests using unique view types for all list items, by assigning the position number to the view type by overriding `getItemViewType()`. Doing so will make the RecyclerView think that all the items in the list have a different type of layout and so each item will be created separately from scratch. This will result in increasing the app's main memory usage and also the load time of the activity or fragment that contains the RecyclerView.**

### Simple Optimal Solution with Explanation

The items are getting shuffled because the item's ViewHolder is not updated properly inside `onBindViewHolder()`. To know why this behavior occurs, first lets understand how exactly the RecyclerView recycles the list items.

By default, the RecyclerView will only create the number of items that can be shown on the device's screen. This means, even if there are hundreds or thousands of list items in the list, if the device can only show 10 items on its screen at a time, then approximately only 10 items will be created and stored in the main memory(RAM). When the screen is scrolled these **same** 10 items will be updated with the new content instead of creating the item and its layout again. In the below image you can see the 1st item getting recycled by only updating the text from ABC to XYZ. The background color red of the previous item remains the same.

[image: recycler view working]

*Image Source: Google Codelabs*

More specifically, while scrolling, instead of garbage collecting the scrolled off item's ViewHolder and creating a new one, the RecyclerView will use the same scrolled off item's ViewHolder and updates it with the upcoming new list item's properties. (A ViewHolder is something that holds the views of a particular list item and the properties that describe it)

This update handling is done by overriding the `onBindViewHolder()` method which gets called whenever a new item needs to be shown on the screen. The reason why the values on your list shuffles have something to do with how the ViewHolder is being updated inside this method. As I said before, since the list items get recycled while scrolling the list, the ViewHolder that you obtain as a parameter for `onBindViewHolder()` **will already be assigned with some other list item's properties**. So, you need to make sure that all the properties of this ViewHolder are either replaced according to your new list item's property or **reset back to the default one**. To do so, check whether you're using any conditions inside this method and make sure that you add a default condition to it that will reset that particular view's property to the default one.

**Example:-**

```java
if (<CONDITION>) {
   holder.textView.setText("New Text")
} else {
   // RESET. Missing to reset the text would lead to the issue.
   holder.textView.setText("Default Text")
}
```

In case if you're still not having a clear understanding of RecyclerView's working then I'd recommend you to go through the [RecyclerView Fundamentals codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#3) by Google. In this codelab they've exclusively addressed this recycling issue in Step 6 of its first task.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since all the others are just a way to make your app less performant.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `getItemId` and `getItemViewType` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

For Kotlin

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```

Insert this. its working .

How to insert?
-> just put this in your adapter class .