# RecyclerView shows only one item at first then only three

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm tearing my hair apart, I'm almost bold !
I'm using a Recyclerview to show a list and each item is a Viewpager for i need each to swipe between information fragments for each item.
The thing is that on loading the fragment, there is only one item loaded, but i can scroll bottom and when I come back to top, only three items are displayed. 
I am completely lost !

Here is my code ! :)

ListIntervention.java

```
public class ListInterventionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListInterventionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<Intervention> mValues;
private FragmentManager mFragment;


public ListInterventionAdapter(FragmentManager context, List<Intervention> items) {
    mValues = items;
    mFragment = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_intervention, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Intervention intervention = mValues.get(position);
    holder.viewPager.setAdapter(new InterventionItemAdapter(mFragment, intervention));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public Intervention mItem;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_intervention_item);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

InterventionItemAdapter.java

```
public class InterventionItemAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Intervention mIntervention;

public InterventionItemAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Intervention intervention) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mIntervention = intervention;
    return;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment interventionFragment;
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            interventionFragment = InterventionMapFragment.newInstance(mIntervention.getId());
            break;
        case 1:
            interventionFragment = InterventionInfoFragment.newInstance(i);
            break;
        case 2:
            interventionFragment = InterventionBlocNote.newInstance(i);
            break;
        default:
            interventionFragment = InterventionMapFragment.newInstance(i);
            break;
    }
    return interventionFragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
 }
```

InterventionMapFragment.java

```
public class InterventionMapFragment extends Fragment {

private View currentView;
private Integer interventionId;

public InterventionMapFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intervention_map_fragment, container, false);
    return currentView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    TextView text = currentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_intervention_map);
    text.setText("MAP " + Integer.toString(this.getArguments().getInt("pos")));
    return;
}

public static InterventionMapFragment newInstance(Integer i) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("pos", i);
    InterventionMapFragment fragment = new InterventionMapFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
}
```

If you want to see the weird results : Here it is !

On load, there is one item

[image]

And if I scroll bottom and go up there are three...

[image]

UPDATE : It appears that the problem comes from the ViewPager called only. 
The viewpager does not always load, it loads either one or only three.

Ideas ?

Comment: Can you show your layout `fragment_intervention` in adapter?

Comment: Why did you return `1` to getCount inside `InterventionItemAdapter`?

Comment: The 1 param was just to limit viewpager to one view (check getItem)
It's the number of pages in the ViewPager :)

Comment: I wonder though, could it be a LinearLayoutManager problem ?

Comment: I really don't think it's a good idea to put ViewPager inside RecyclerView....I think you should definitely consider changing your implementation.

Comment: Thanks hardartcore ! To explain you my needs : 
We are listing interventions for electricians, the card has the intervention info if they swipe left they have a map, if they swipe right they have what they have to do. And we though Viewpager was a good solution. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that your layout fragment_intervention_map_fragment the height in your parent layout is set to match parent.

the correct implementation is set your height in your parent layout to wrap_content

Comment: Still the same problem after correcting what you said :)

Comment: public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_intervention_item);
        return;
    }

I never use return; in my view holder class. what does it do by the way ? maybe thats the cause

Comment: public InterventionItemAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Intervention intervention) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mIntervention = intervention;
    return;
}

can you remove this return; also ? and try if maybe it solves your problem

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I used the return just to debug the function. :)

Comment: @Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
maybe this is the issue, there is only getItemCount()

Comment: @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {    
    return position;
} 
add this also. this should prevent changing item on scroll recyclerview

Comment: As I said above, it was just to limit the number of pages loaded in Viewpager =)

Comment: have you try @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) { return position; }  ???

Comment: Returning getItemViewType as position is basically asking to draw every view again and nothing gets recylcled. You might as well set viewholder.setIsRecylable(false) while creating viewholder. But this would defeat the purpose of having a recylerview. This answer just masks the real issue. from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200540/recyclerview-on-scrolling-values-changing-from-adapter

Comment: Okay, but I think it is not related to my issue ? One displayed first, then three, whereas I have 10 to display..