# Edittext values & checkbox cleared automcally RecyclerView items when scorlling in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView on android. In RecyclerView items, I have the checkbox & editextField. But when I scroll RecyclerView after entering values, values are cleared.
I need to keep the checkbox checked & edittext value in the field if I scroll recycleView.

Here is my image:
[image]

Here is my Adapter:

```
    public class AdapterSectionRecycler extends SectionRecyclerViewAdapter<SectionHeader, Child, SectionViewHolder, ChildViewHolder> {

        Context context;
        private final OnItemClickListener listener;
        int count = 0;
        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(Child child,Boolean isChecked);
            void onTextPercentageChange(String answerId, String percentage);
            void headerTextChange(String questionName,String SurveyQuestionId, String SurveyQuestionTypeId,String SurveyPercentage);
        }

        public AdapterSectionRecycler(Context context,int count, List<SectionHeader> sectionItemList,OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(context, sectionItemList);
            this.context = context;
            this.count = count;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public SectionViewHolder onCreateSectionViewHolder(ViewGroup sectionViewGroup, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.section_item, sectionViewGroup, false);
            return new SectionViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public ChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, childViewGroup, false);
            return new ChildViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindSectionViewHolder(SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder, int i, SectionHeader sectionHeader) {
          
            sectionViewHolder.name.setText(sectionHeader.getSectionText());
            sectionViewHolder.tv_question_id.setText(sectionHeader.getQuestionId());
            sectionViewHolder.tv_question_type_id.setText(sectionHeader.getQuestionTypeId());
            sectionViewHolder.edHeaderPercentage.setText(sectionHeader.getPercentage());
            

           
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindChildViewHolder(ChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int i, int positon, Child child) {
        
            childViewHolder.chk_answer.setText(child.getAnswerName());
            childViewHolder.tv_surveyAnswerId.setText(String.valueOf(child.getAnswerId()));
            childViewHolder.chk_answer.setChecked(false);
            
            childViewHolder.etPercentage.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);  

    }
```

Here is my ViewHolder Class:

```
        public class ChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
        CheckBox chk_answer;
        EditText etPercentage;
        EditText etsl;
        TextView tv_surveyAnswerId;
    
        public ChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chk_answer = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chk_answer);
            etPercentage = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etPercentage);
            etsl = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etsl);
            tv_surveyAnswerId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_surveyAnswerId);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to keep value if I scroll recycleview.

Answer (score 0):

Just Override these methods in your adapter class:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35200540/recyclerview-on-scrolling-values-changing-from-adapter)

Comment: I have already used above getItemId(), getItemViewType method